# What is the easiest way to change the JS code so that when I insert an entry separated with a comma it will display them as separate listings?

Tags: javascript

1. In this application, you’ll make an enhancement that allows you to enter multiple tasks separated by commas in a single entry.
2. Run the application and add two tasks, separated by a comma. Note that the tasks are stored as one task, exactly as you entered it.
3. In the JavaScript file, find the code in the addToTaskList function that adds the task entered by the user to the tasks array. Comment out that code, and replace it with code that works for one task in an entry and also for more than one task in an entry.

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m04G8.png)

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var tasks = [];

var displayTaskList = function() {
    var list = "";
    // if there are no tasks in tasks array, check storage
    if (tasks.length === 0) {
        // get tasks from storage or empty string if nothing in storage
        var storage = localStorage.getItem("tasks") || "";
        // if not empty, convert to array and store in global tasks variable
        if (storage.length > 0) {
          tasks = storage.split("|");
        }
    }
    // if there are tasks in array, sort and create tasks string
    if (tasks.length > 0) {
        tasks.sort();
        list = tasks.join("\n");
    }
    // display tasks string and set focus on task text box
    $("task_list").value = list;
    $("task").focus();
};

var addToTaskList = function() {
    var task = $("task");
    if (task.value === "") {
        alert("Please enter a task.");
    } else {
        // add task to array and local storage
        tasks.push(task.value);
        localStorage.tasks = tasks.join("|");
        // clear task text box and re-display tasks
        task.value = "";
        displayTaskList();
    }
};

// add task to array and local storage
if(task.value.indexOf(',') == -1 ){
  tasks.push(task.value);
}
localStorage.tasks = tasks.join("|");
        // clear task text box and re-display tasks
        task.value = "";
        displayTaskList();
    }
};

var clearTaskList = function() {
    tasks.length = 0;
    localStorage.tasks = "";
    $("task_list").value = "";
    $("task").focus();
};

window.onload = function() {
    $("add_task").onclick = addToTaskList;
    $("clear_tasks").onclick = clearTaskList;
    displayTaskList();
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid blue;
 padding: 0 2em 1em;
}
h1 { 
    font-size: 150%;
    color: blue;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 8em;
}
input {
    width: 22em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#tasks {
    margin-top: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ch09 Task Manager</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="task_list.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="task_list.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <h1>Task Manager</h1>
    <div id="tasks">
        <label for="tasks">Task List</label><br>
        <textarea id="task_list" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>

    <label for="task">Task</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="task" id="task"><br>

    <input type="button" name="add_task" id="add_task" value="Add Task"><br>
    <input type="button" name="clear_tasks" id="clear_tasks" value="Clear Tasks">
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [your other deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177934/how-do-i-checks).

Answer (score 0):

not sure may be this help

```
var addToTaskList = function() {
  var task = $("task");
  if (task.value === "") {
    alert("Please enter a task.");
  } else {
        localStorage.tasks = localStorage.tasks+"|"+task.value.replace(/,/g, '|');
        tasks = [];
        task.value = "";
        displayTaskList();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function `String.split` can be used to split a text into an array of smaller texts using the specified text as a separator.
The function `addToTaskList` could be changed to :

```
    var addToTaskList = function() {
        var task = $("task");
        if (task.value === "") {
            alert("Please enter a task.");
        } else {
            // split new tasks in individual tasks
            var newTasks = task.value.split(',');
            //remove whitespaces from both ends of each task
            newTasks = newTasks.map(task=>task.trim());
            //if a task is empty, remove it from the array.
            newTasks = newTasks.filter(t=>t.length > 0);

            // add task to array and local storage
            tasks.push(...newTasks); // new syntax from ES6 (2015).
            //you can do the same thing with the old syntax :
            //Array.prorotype.push.apply(tasks, newTasks)

            localStorage.tasks = tasks.join("|");
            // clear task text box and re-display tasks
            task.value = "";
            displayTaskList();
        }
    };
```